# How to implement Bootstrap styling into dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

**Question:** I am trying to create new HTML elements dynamically, but the 'pre-made' bootstrap styling isn't rendering on the elements. Why would this be the case?

The elements are loading on the page, but they are just bland HTML elements.

**ATTEMPTS:** I have read the other forums, but surely there are other ways that don't involve hard-coding the actual bootstrap style attributes as CSS? Otherwise, I have seen some solutions that simply '.append()' the whole element they want, but I would like to know why my code doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/album/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="tail.select-default.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main role="main">
        <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" id = "row">
  </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </main>

    <footer class="text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="float-right">
                <a href="#">Back to top</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.3/assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')

    </script>
    <script src="dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="tail.select-full.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        tail.select('#select2', {
            search: true,
            descriptions: true,
            hideSelected: true,
            hideDisabled: true,
            multiShowCount: false,
            multiContainer: true
        });
    </script>

    <script src="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

An example of the HTML I want to implement:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail">
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect class='rect' width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" />
            <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
        </svg>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Project1</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript file: (I first grab some info from a database before creating the new elements, so you can skip over the first bits)

```
var svg_width = '100%';
var svg_height = '225';
var svg_xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg_AspectRatio = "xMidYMid slice";
var svg_focusable = "false";
var svg_role = "img";
var svg_label= "Placeholder: Thumbnail";

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!")

    //getting all of the data from the index
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:9200/demo/_search?q=*", function(data){

        //getting the total number of hits
        var totalHits = data.hits.total;
        var arrayHits = data.hits.hits;

        //console.log(data)
        //console.log(arrayHits)

        console.log(totalHits)
        if (totalHits != 0 ) {

            //getting the length of the arrat for the for loop
            var arrayLength = arrayHits.length;

            //starting the for loop
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                console.log(arrayHits[i])

                //getting the required variables
                var uuid = arrayHits[i]['_id'];
                var title = arrayHits[i]['_source']['title'];
                var firstName = arrayHits[i]['_source']['firstName'];
                var lastName = arrayHits[i]['_source']['lastName'];
                var importance = arrayHits[i]['_source']['importance'];
                var description = arrayHits[i]['_source']['description'];

                // creating the actual elements now
                var d2 = document.createElement('div');
                d2.className= 'col-md-4';

                //appending what we have made to the pre-existing HTML
                document.getElementById("row").appendChild(d2);

                var d3 = document.createElement('div');
                d3.className = 'card mb-4 shadow-sm';

                var svg1 = document.createElement('svg');
                svg1.className = 'bd-placeholder-img card-img-top';
                svg1.setAttribute('width',svg_width);
                svg1.setAttribute('height',svg_height);
                svg1.setAttribute('xmlns',svg_xmlns);
                svg1.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio",svg_AspectRatio);
                svg1.setAttribute('focusable',svg_focusable);
                svg1.setAttribute('role',svg_role);
                svg1.setAttribute('aria-label',svg_label);

                var t1 = document.createElement('title');
                t1_text = document.createTextNode('Placeholder');

                var rect_text_group = document.createElement('g');

                var rect = document.createElement('rect');
                rect.setAttribute('width','100%');
                rect.setAttribute('height','100%');
                rect.setAttribute('fill','#55595c');

                var rect_text = document.createElement('text');
                rect_text.setAttribute('x','50%');
                rect_text.setAttribute('y','50%');
                rect_text.setAttribute('fill','#eceeef');
                rect_text.setAttribute('dy','.3em');

                var rect_text_text = document.createTextNode("Thumbnail");

                var d4 = document.createElement('div');
                d4.className = "card-body";

                var p1 = document.createElement('p');
                p1.className = 'card-text';
                var p1_text = document.createTextNode(title)

                var d5 = document.createElement('div');
                d5.className = "d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";

                var d6 = document.createElement('div');
                d6.className = "btn-group";

                //defining the two buttons
                var btn1 = document.createElement("button");
                btn1.className = "btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary";
                btn1.setAttribute('type','button');
                var btn1_text = document.createTextNode('View');

                var btn2 = document.createElement("button");
                btn2.className = "btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary";
                btn2.setAttribute('type','button');
                var btn2_text = document.createTextNode('Edit');

                var small = document.createElement('small');
                small.className = 'text-muted';
                var small_text = document.createTextNode('9 mins');

                //append child bits

                d2.appendChild(d3);

                d3.appendChild(svg1);
                svg1.appendChild(t1);
                t1.appendChild(t1_text);
                svg1.appendChild(rect_text_group);
                rect_text_group.appendChild(rect);
                rect_text_group.appendChild(rect_text);
                rect_text.appendChild(rect_text_text);
                //rect_text.appendChild(rect_text_text);

                d3.appendChild(d4);
                d4.appendChild(p1);
                p1.appendChild(p1_text);

                d4.appendChild(d5);
                d5.appendChild(d6);

                d6.appendChild(btn1);
                btn1.appendChild(btn1_text);
                d6.appendChild(btn2);
                btn2.appendChild(btn2_text);

                d4.appendChild(small);
                small.appendChild(small_text);

            }   
        } else {
            console.log('Nothing in the database')
        }
    });
});
```

Expected: styled
Reality: just bare-bones HTML

Comment: So is the example HTML the output you want? What does your code output? Can you try to find the differences between them? Because your way of adding classNames is fine!

Comment: @A1rPun - yes, I want to create elements like that (w/o buttons for now) and the code is successfully doing that (I checked the html code on chrome and it looks the same). Also, thanks for the edits.

Comment: I found missing height & width attributes, which I have added now - however, still makes no style change. Might it have something to do with the way that I have structured the `<rect>` and `<text>` elements. I have put them in a group, as per other stackoverflow posts have suggested, but has not made any difference. However, in the desired HTML element, there is only one `<rect>` label; but in my created code, there is also a closing tag - would this make a difference?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I still miss some context like a screenshot of what you see. When I put your HTML code in a (bootstrap 4) fiddle it looks like a normal card component with 2 buttons on it.

Comment: @A1rPun - thanks for the response. When you look at it, does it look like the cards do here? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/album/

Comment: Yes, but more material-like. [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3feug95x/).

Comment: @A1rPun - that is interesting, mine doesn't look like that. Will try to get a screenshot loaded soon.

Comment: for anyone who has the same issue, it was that the ```<svg>``` tags weren't able to be loaded by my browser and instead needed to be replaced with ```<img>``` tags (and change a couple of attributes)